# Pyspark not reading data from kafka stream

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, apache-kafka

I'm using PySpark to read streaming data from kafka. Both kafka and PySpark are running in a local kubernetes cluster setup using minikube. I am using the bitnami/spark-cluster helm chart. It seems that the PySpark app is unable to read streaming data from Kafka.

Here are some logs from the pyspark app -

```
22/12/18 20:40:57 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20221218203946-0013/5 on hostPort 172.17.0.4:40893 with 1 core(s), 1024.0 MiB RAM
22/12/18 20:40:57 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka version: 2.6.0
22/12/18 20:40:57 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId: 62abe01bee039651
22/12/18 20:40:57 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka startTimeMs: 1671396057484
22/12/18 20:40:57 INFO KafkaConsumer: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0] Subscribed to topic(s): meetup-rsvps-topic
22/12/18 20:40:57 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20221218203946-0013/5 is now RUNNING
22/12/18 20:41:04 INFO Metadata: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0] Cluster ID: tIhn8pqNQbWmb6C_WDce3A
22/12/18 20:41:04 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0] Discovered group coordinator kafka-local-0.kafka-local-headless.meetupstream.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
22/12/18 20:41:04 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0] (Re-)joining group
22/12/18 20:41:05 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.MemberIdRequiredException: The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group.
22/12/18 20:41:05 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0] (Re-)joining group
22/12/18 20:41:05 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0] Finished assignment for group at generation 1: {consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1-8ff6df17-88f3-48dd-86f1-caa731cfbfab=Assignment(partitions=[meetup-rsvps-topic-0])}
22/12/18 20:41:05 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0] Successfully joined group with generation 1
22/12/18 20:41:05 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[meetup-rsvps-topic-0])
22/12/18 20:41:05 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0] Adding newly assigned partitions: meetup-rsvps-topic-0
22/12/18 20:41:05 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0] Found no committed offset for partition meetup-rsvps-topic-0
22/12/18 20:41:06 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0] Seeking to EARLIEST offset of partition meetup-rsvps-topic-0
22/12/18 20:41:06 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition meetup-rsvps-topic-0 to offset 0.
22/12/18 20:41:06 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Writing atomically to file:/tmp/temporary-a95fafb4-6113-49ab-93d8-b0c495bac40a/sources/0/0 using temp file file:/tmp/temporary-a95fafb4-6113-49ab-93d8-b0c495bac40a/sources/0/.0.e93bfa5b-6db8-4892-8447-a500739de876.tmp
22/12/18 20:41:07 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Renamed temp file file:/tmp/temporary-a95fafb4-6113-49ab-93d8-b0c495bac40a/sources/0/.0.e93bfa5b-6db8-4892-8447-a500739de876.tmp to file:/tmp/temporary-a95fafb4-6113-49ab-93d8-b0c495bac40a/sources/0/0
22/12/18 20:41:07 INFO KafkaMicroBatchStream: Initial offsets: {"meetup-rsvps-topic":{"0":0}}
22/12/18 20:41:07 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0] Seeking to LATEST offset of partition meetup-rsvps-topic-0
22/12/18 20:41:07 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-bfcc8f10-c42a-4320-a4bf-735d75f3893b--1704904730-driver-0] Resetting offset for partition meetup-rsvps-topic-0 to offset 1898.
22/12/18 20:41:07 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Writing atomically to file:/tmp/temporary-a95fafb4-6113-49ab-93d8-b0c495bac40a/offsets/0 using temp file file:/tmp/temporary-a95fafb4-6113-49ab-93d8-b0c495bac40a/offsets/.0.a9f679ba-5f6a-4ca5-9e3d-4e7ac92d3afa.tmp
22/12/18 20:41:09 INFO CheckpointFileManager: Renamed temp file file:/tmp/temporary-a95fafb4-6113-49ab-93d8-b0c495bac40a/offsets/.0.a9f679ba-5f6a-4ca5-9e3d-4e7ac92d3afa.tmp to file:/tmp/temporary-a95fafb4-6113-49ab-93d8-b0c495bac40a/offsets/0
22/12/18 20:41:09 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Committed offsets for batch 0. Metadata OffsetSeqMetadata(0,1671396067279,Map(spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass -> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider, spark.sql.streaming.join.stateFormatVersion -> 2, spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.compression.codec -> lz4, spark.sql.streaming.flatMapGroupsWithState.stateFormatVersion -> 2, spark.sql.streaming.multipleWatermarkPolicy -> min, spark.sql.streaming.aggregation.stateFormatVersion -> 2, spark.sql.shuffle.partitions -> 200))
22/12/18 20:41:15 INFO KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer: Partitions added: Map()
22/12/18 20:41:16 INFO KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer: Partitions added: Map()
22/12/18 20:41:16 INFO KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer: Partitions added: Map()
22/12/18 20:41:16 INFO KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer: Partitions added: Map()
22/12/18 20:41:17 INFO KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer: Partitions added: Map()
22/12/18 20:41:17 INFO KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer: Partitions added: Map()
22/12/18 20:41:31 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 4801.506531 ms
22/12/18 20:41:33 INFO WriteToDataSourceV2Exec: Start processing data source write support: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.MicroBatchWrite@53fa8f13. The input RDD has 1 partitions.
22/12/18 20:41:33 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: start at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0
22/12/18 20:41:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (start at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) with 1 output partitions
22/12/18 20:41:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (start at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0)
22/12/18 20:41:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
22/12/18 20:41:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
22/12/18 20:41:33 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20221218203946-0013/5 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
22/12/18 20:41:33 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20221218203946-0013/5 removed: Command exited with code 1
22/12/18 20:41:33 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 5 requested
22/12/18 20:41:33 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 5
22/12/18 20:41:33 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20221218203946-0013/6 on worker-20221217144830-172.17.0.4-40893 (172.17.0.4:40893) with 1 core(s)
22/12/18 20:41:33 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 5 from BlockManagerMaster.
22/12/18 20:41:33 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20221218203946-0013/6 on hostPort 172.17.0.4:40893 with 1 core(s), 1024.0 MiB RAM
22/12/18 20:41:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at start at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0), which has no missing parents
22/12/18 20:41:33 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20221218203946-0013/6 is now RUNNING
22/12/18 20:41:34 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20221218203946-0013/4 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
22/12/18 20:41:34 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20221218203946-0013/4 removed: Command exited with code 1
22/12/18 20:41:34 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20221218203946-0013/7 on worker-20221217144749-172.17.0.3-46817 (172.17.0.3:46817) with 1 core(s)
22/12/19 10:35:09 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20221219103231-0000/9 on hostPort 172.17.0.4:35303 with 1 core(s), 1024.0 MiB RAM
22/12/19 10:35:09 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20221219103231-0000/9 on hostPort 172.17.0.4:35303 with 1 core(s), 1024.0 MiB RAM
22/12/19 10:35:09 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 7 from BlockManagerMaster.
22/12/19 10:35:09 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 7 requested
22/12/19 10:35:09 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 7
22/12/19 10:35:09 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20221219103231-0000/9 is now RUNNING
22/12/19 10:35:18 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
22/12/19 10:35:25 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20221219103231-0000/8 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
22/12/19 10:35:25 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20221219103231-0000/8 removed: Command exited with code 1
22/12/19 10:35:25 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20221219103231-0000/10 on worker-20221219102048-172.17.0.3-33275 (172.17.0.3:33275) with 1 core(s)
22/12/19 10:35:25 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20221219103231-0000/10 on hostPort 172.17.0.3:33275 with 1 core(s), 1024.0 MiB RAM
22/12/19 10:35:25 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 8 from BlockManagerMaster.
22/12/19 10:35:25 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 8 requested
```

Here is the code for my pyspark app.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

def main():

    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("SparkProcess") \
        .getOrCreate()
    
    df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka-local.meetupstream.svc.cluster.local:9092")
        .option("subscribe", "meetup-rsvps-topic")
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
        .load() 

    df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

    df.writeStream \
        .trigger(processingTime="60 seconds") \
        .format("console") \
        .outputMode("append") \
        .start()
```

I have also tried setting `.config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")` in PySpark but I still get the same error.

My spark UI -
[image]

I am using the following command for executing my spark app -
`kubectl run spark-base -it --rm --labels="app=spark-client"  --image-pull-policy Never --restart Never   --image spark-layer:latest -- bash ./spark/bin/spark-submit --master spark://spark-cluster-master-svc:7077     --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.1    ./spark-process.py`

Comment: `job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources`

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, I have googled the warning but can't find any solution. I saw a suggestion to disable dynamicAllocation which I already did but still facing the problem. I have attached a screenshot of my spark UI in the question.

Comment: Have you tried giving your executors less memory? There's only 2.3G available total, so you'll have limited space to run executors each at 1G

Comment: How can I do that? I am using the following command for executing my spark app - `kubectl run spark-base -it --rm --labels="app=spark-client"  --image-pull-policy Never --restart Never   --image spark-layer:latest -- bash ./spark/bin/spark-submit --master spark://spark-cluster-master-svc:7077     --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.1    ./spark-process.py`

Comment: `--executor-memory 512MB`, for example... https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: You can also use k8s as your executor environment. You don't need to use Spark Standalone within Kubernetes

Comment: I tried with executor-memory 512MB but still getting the same error.

Comment: It's a warning, rather than an error. Your code is running fine. You will only see console output in the executor logs however, not your kubernetes command terminal

Comment: Oh so I kubectl exec into the executor and checked /spark/conf/log4j.properties.template. I found `log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console``log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender`. There is no dir `/var/log/spark`. Where can I find the logs in executor then?

Comment: No, not log4j logs. From the Spark UI, you can click into each executor/worker and see their console outputs

Comment: Ah that is not an option for me. I can using port-forwarding to view the spark UI `kubectl port-forward --namespace meetupstream svc/spark-cluster-master-svc 8090:80` when I click on the worker to see their logs I just get `Unable to connect to http://172.17.0.3:8080/`. I guess I would need some port forwarding magic to view this. Any other option by which I can see these logs? By kubectl exec into the worker perhaps?

Comment: You'll need to port-forward the executors as well, but those are dynamic, so may not work too well. You could try using `--deploy-mode=client` and/or `--master='local[*]'` to see logs from that container. Otherwise, write the data to a new Kafka topic or a database rather than the console... Or, another solution would be to just use `kafka-python` and not need Spark